# Android: Swipe to refresh gets stuck on a recycler view with view pager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout

Here is my XML code

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/flipper">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_appointment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_event_note"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The `RecyclerView`s adapter supports two types of views one is `CardView` and another is `ViewPager`.

When I swipe to refresh, the circular refresh icon freezes on top of the `ViewPager`.onrefresh method is called after I tap the refresh icon again.Is there any fix to this issue?